# Java Web Service operation

Tags: java, web-services

I have a set of statements to be executed repeatedly every time a web method is called with a new service.I tried writing in the constructor but, the constructor gets invoked only once when the server starts. Instead, I need the set of stmts to be executed each time a Service is created at the client.

Answer (score 0):

As per your other quuestion: maybe [interceptors](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&ei=3W6SSrfRA8uN_AacgNmuAg&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&q=JAX+WS+interceptor&spell=1&fp=458d05167c37f829) will help

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for @PostConstruct:

```
@javax.annotation.PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(){
    // initialization code
}
```

A method annotated with @PostConstruct is called by the container once after the bean is instantiated.

**EDIT:** I think, I misunderstood your question. You're probably looking for interceptors as suggested by djna, i.e., `javax.ejb.Interceptors` annotation. You can find a good introduction [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/meeraj/archive/2006/01/interceptors_wi.html) (as soon as maintenance of java.net is over).